# Matlab PCA vs Mapcaplot

Tags: matlab, data-analysis, pca

Can someone please explain what the built in function PCA does in comparison to the Mapcaplot?

How do I take the outputs from the PCA function and make the plots the Mapcaplot makes, so I can understand what it's doing?

Documentation:

[Mapcaplot](https://au.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/mapcaplot.html#d126e124328)

[PCA](https://au.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html)

Comment: I've figured out the Mapcaplot is the columns of the PCA "score" matrix plotted against one another